# Use RAW Eloquent Queries with Slim PHP

Tags: php, eloquent

I am working on a project with SlimPHP and Eloquent. 
I am trying to run a RAW SQL query within a Model's method, like this:

/models/Form.php

```
<?php
namespace models;

class Form extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model {

protected $table = 'forms';

public function getResponses($form_id)
{
    // HERE
    $select = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::select('select 1');
    return 1;
}

}
```

I am using Capsule to bootstrap the ORM.

The code above gives me:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function select() on a non-object in
>   /vagrant/vendor/illuminate/support/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php
>   on line 208

Documentation is of very help in this case, could you shed some light on this?

thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Read the [setup instructions on github](https://github.com/illuminate/database#usage-instructions) closely and make sure you follow them correctly.

---

With Capsule you should use `Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager` or  as `DB` "Facade".

```
$select = \Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager::select('select 1');
```

I usually import it and define an alias:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as DB;

// ...

$select = DB::select('select 1');
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, with that I am having now:

Fatal error: Call to a member function getConnection() on a non-object in /vagrant/vendor/illuminate/database/Illuminate/Database/Capsule/Manager.php,

Does it make any sense to you?, cheers!

Comment: Did you follow the install instructions on [github](https://github.com/illuminate/database)?

Comment: That was it, I missed the $capsule->setAsGlobal(); in order to be able to access the connection instance globally, thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Plus if you need to do raw query, it may help to call setAsGlobal() after bootEloquent() like this

```
$capsule->addConnection($sqliteDb);
$capsule->bootEloquent();
$capsule->setAsGlobal();   // <--- this
```

Answer (score 0):

In  Slim 4,
we can use $this->getConnection()->select($sql);

```
 <?php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class Product extends Model{

    protected $table = 'products';
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = ["name", "price", "quantity", "supplier", "image", "category"];

    public function getProductsByCategory(){
        $sql = 'SELECT p.id,
                        p.name,
                        p.price,
                        p.quantity,
                        p.supplier,
                        p.image,
                        p.category,
                (SELECT IF(COUNT(*) >= 1, TRUE, FALSE) FROM favorite f WHERE f.user_id = 1 AND f.product_id = p.id) AS isFavourite,
                (SELECT IF(COUNT(*) >= 1, TRUE, FALSE) FROM carts c WHERE c.user_id = 1 AND c.product_id = p.id) AS isInCart
                FROM products p';

        return $this->getConnection()->select($sql);
    }   
}
```